# How to fix onclick not triggering if the div is empty?

Tags: javascript, php, html, onclick

I am working on a backend site for members and volunteers of my scoutgroup.
I have a calendar page which is just a nice table build from the database for every row the division has (there a 2 divisions). Only Fridays, Saturdays and Sundays are added. I do it this way because we are used to a google sheet.

(Yes I know duplicate entries etc. but this is the optimal way in this case).

Now the issue I am having:
[The html table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GrqyL.png)

A row is build in php on base of an sql:

```
 <?php
 while ($result && ($row = $result_fetch_assoc())){
     echo"
         <tr>
             <td>" . $row['day'] . "</td>
             <td>" . $row['date'] . "</td>
             <td id='typestd" . $row['idPlanning'] . "'><div onclick='edittype_js(" . $row['idPlanning'] . ")'>" . $row['type'] . "</div></td>
             <td id='descriptiontd" . $row['idPlanning'] . "'><div onclick='editdescr_js(" . $row['idPlanning'] . ")'>" . $row['description'] . "</div></td>
          </tr>
          ";
    ...
```

The `onclick` does a GET from type or description php file which echo's with a javascript inner html into the `<td>`, so it 'overwrites' the div with the onclick:

```
 <?php
 echo"<input class='form-control' value='" . $row['type'] . "' autofocus></input>";
 ?>
```

Now the problem is that the onclick only trigger if the cell is filled. If it is empty it doesn't. I want it to be so ones you click on it you can edit the text and on enter it saves the cell.

The saving on enter I can probably figure out but how do I make it so the onclick will also trigger on empty cells? (moving it to the  works but then you can't edit and click on your text)

Comment: Add the onclicks to your TD elements, if the div is empty, it doesn't render. Also it might be worth checking if the field is empty and substituting it for a `&nbsp;` if it is.

Comment: Can you give us a working example?  As in, not the .php, but the outputted html and javascript?  Parsing through your php doesn't give the whole picture.

Comment: But then how would you work around the fact that you can't click in the cell without resetting it? I have users that would click to edit a typo instead of use arrow keys? @R.Chappell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the onClick to the td tags. When a div is empty it will not render / will have no size, so the user will not be able to click it and therefor the function won't trigger.

```
<?php
 while ($result && ($row = $result_fetch_assoc())){
     echo"
         <tr>
             <td>" . $row['day'] . "</td>
             <td>" . $row['date'] . "</td>
             <td id='typestd" . $row['idPlanning'] . "' onclick='edittype_js(" . $row['idPlanning'] . ")'><div>" . $row['type'] . "</div></td>
             <td id='descriptiontd" . $row['idPlanning'] . "' onclick='editdescr_js(" . $row['idPlanning'] . ")'><div>" . $row['description'] . "</div></td>
          </tr>
          ";
    ...
```

Comment: But then how would you work around the fact that you can't click in the cell without resetting it? I have users that would click to edit a typo instead of use arrow keys?

Comment: I'm not quite sure exactly what you mean. Could you explain exactly what you're creating with this table.